# Parameter passing for http.post in Angular calling Java web API

Tags: java, angular, web-services

I have a weird situation that may be because I missed something that I didn't realized or know.
I am creating a simple login UI using Angular and call the Web API created in Java.

The Java web API function is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logon", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public String logon(
        @RequestParam(value = "userID", required = true) String userID,
        @RequestParam(value = "password", required = true) String password,
        HttpServletRequest request)
```

Now if I use the `http.post` as follows:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post(this.url+"/security/logon/", 
                          JSON.stringify({ userID: username, password: password }) )
```

Then I get the following error in the Google Chrome browser:

> POST http://localhost:8080/logon/ 400 (Required String parameter 'userID' is not present)

But if I change the code as follows:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    var usrpwd = "userID=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    return this.http.post(this.url+"/security/logon?"+usrpwd, usrpwd )
```

It work perfectly.
Am I missing something? Why the second parameter of `http.post` that should be the parameter passed not seems to be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining your endpoint url with two mandatory parameters, and such parameters must be in the url (check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)), so when you make a request to your endpoint, the url must be :

http://localhost:8080/logon?userID=yourUserId&password=yourUserPassword

In the first implementation you are not adding the query parameters to the url so the request is made to the url *http://localhost:8080/logon/* as it doesn't have the required parameters, your web tier is returning the [400 http code](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_httpmessages.asp), which implies a bad request (because again, your url doesn't contains the required parameters).

Comment: Thank you very much for the enlightenment. Now I understand at least there are 2 ways to pass parameters to a web API.

Comment: Glad to know it works for you :) if you considerer the answer useful mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 constructor(private http:HttpClient){
```

}

login(usrName,usrPwd){

`let body = {userName:usrName, userPwd:usrPwd};

    this.http.post("http://localhost:5000/security/login", body)
        .subscribe(
            res => console.log(res),
            error => console.log(error)
        )
}`